# Asynchronously Apply Bindings in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am having difficult time understanding how I can asynchronously bind my cascading Select2 drop-down fields using knockoutJS.

The code works perfectly when the data to be populated is static within the function, however does not work when using an asynchronous ajax call as the binding is executed prior to the response being received.

Can anyone guide me into the right direction or spot an issue as I am a knockout.js beginner?

**Knockout**

```
var viewModel = {
    togaMakers: buildData(),
    selectedInstitution : ko.observable(),
    selectedLevel : ko.observable(),
    selectedFaculty : ko.observable()
};

viewModel.togaLevels = ko.computed(function(){
    if(viewModel.selectedInstitution()){
        var make = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.togaMakers,function(item){
            //console.log(item.text,viewModel.selectedInstitution());
                return item.text===viewModel.selectedInstitution();          
        });
        return make.childOptions;
    } 
});

viewModel.togaFaculties = ko.computed(function(){
    if(viewModel.selectedLevel()){
        var type = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.togaLevels(),function(item){
            //console.log(item.text,viewModel.selectedLevel());
                return item.text===viewModel.selectedLevel();
          //console.log("Answer:" + item);
        });
        return type.childOptions;
    } 
});
ko.cleanNode(viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**buildData()**

```
function buildData() {
    var gotData = getData();

    return gotData.then(function() {
        console.log('step 4 - return result');
        returnData = gotData;
        return returnData;
    });
}
```

**getData()**

```
// Get all data from ajax call
function getData() {
    var data = { 'action': 'get_data' };
    var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();

    return jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        // console.log(response);
        console.log('step 1 - parse ajax data');
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log('step 2 - process received data');
        results = processData(obj);
    }).done(function() {
        console.log('step 3 - ajax parsing & processing data done');
        console.log(results);
        deferred.resolve(results);
        return deferred;
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('fail');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildData` needs to return an `observable` in order for your binding to be automatically updated once the data changes:

```
function buildData() {
  var dataContainer = ko.observableArray([]);

  getData().then(function(newData) {
    console.log('step 4 - return result');
    dataContainer(newData);
  });

  return dataContainer; // Initially empty array
};
```

I'd personally define the array in your `viewModel` first though, and write to it inside the `then` by referencing it. Might help if you use a class/instance based approach so you can reference the dataContainer using `this`... But I guess that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you for this, it has been a very helpful & super quick reply! You my friend saved the day!